# Adicionar elementos Programaticamente

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Eu tenho uma determinada parte de um aplicativo no qual há um questionário randômico. Gerado pelo próprio usuário. A questão é: eu não tenho acesso a quantidade de perguntas ou quais são as perguntas prontamente. Portanto, eu tenho que obter tudo isso dinamicamente. Logo, o questionário tem que ser dinâmico. E aí consiste minha dúvida. Eu já obtive tudo. Porém na hora de montar eu não estou conseguindo.

Eu uso um `ViewFlipper` para as diversas questões. Dentro desse `ViewFlipper` ficam os layouts com as questões. Eu utilizo um `ScrollView` e dentro do `ScrollView` um `RelativeLayout` para montar as perguntas. Não sei se essa é a maneira correta porém funciona quando utilizo um questionário fixo.

Eu estou tendo quebra de layout ao tentar inserir os elementos dinamicamente.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsRelativeLayout.setMargins(16, 16, 16, 16);

mainLayout = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);

for(int i = 0; i < perguntasLabel.length; i++) {
    viewNotList = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());
    viewNotList.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mainLayout.addView(viewNotList);

    viewNotListChild = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
    viewNotListChild.setLayoutParams(paramsRelativeLayout);
    viewNotListChild.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.padrao));
    viewNotList.addView(viewNotListChild);

    titulo = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    titulo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    titulo.setText(perguntasLabel[i]);
    titulo.setTextSize(20);
    viewNotListChild.addView(titulo);


    if (perguntasTipo[i].equals("datepicker")) {
        EditText input = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        input.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        input.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.input));
        viewNotListChild.addView(input);

    }
}
```

Comment: Defina "quebra de layout".

Comment: Vc está tendo crash? Cole o stack de erro caso sim. Ou então, poste um screenshot de como fica a tela quando vc usa esse código.

Comment: Obrigado pelo interesse. Tá resolvido! O problema era que eu estava criando um formulário e os elementos estavam subindo um em cima do outro. Estava me esquecendo basicamente de adicionar uma regra para below e setar o id.

Comment: Por favor, coloque a solução como uma resposta e preferencialmente aceite-a. Você ajuda outras pessoas e ainda pode ganhar reputação.

Comment: @user5023 "O problema era que eu estava criando um formulário e os elementos estavam subindo um em cima do outro. Estava me esquecendo basicamente de adicionar uma regra para below e setar o id." Já que os elementos são como uma lista de perguntas, não seria mais interessante trocar esse relativelayout por um linearlayout? cada nova view criada seria adicionada abaixo da anterior.

Comment: @AnselmoMS seria uma boa idéia também. Na verdade a opção por relative se deu pois já havia um formulário estruturado utilizado ele na aplicação. Então aproveitei. Mas irei levar em consideração o que foi dito em formulários futuros.

Answer (score 1):

Como disse, o problema foi solucionado da seguinte forma.

Ao criar uma `View` foi informado seu ID.

```
view.setId(INTEIRO);
```

E no `LayoutParams` da próxima `View` foi adicionado uma regra.

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, viewAnterior.getId());
```

Esse não é o jeito correto, muito provavelmente. Achei meio gambiarra mas seguiu o padrão que já havia sido estabelecido nos demais formulários da aplicação.
Talvez, como sugeriu @AnselmoMs, a melhor opção tivesse sido utilizar um `LinearLayout`.